# HTML and JS, hide tome table inside divs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code like this:

I have some html code like this:

```
<div id="mapLegendInside">
   <div>
      <table>
         // code
      </table>
      <div>
         <table class="esriLegendLayerLabel">
            // code
         </table>
         <table class="esriLegendLayer"> <--- I need to hide this table
            // code
         </table>
         <table class="esriLegendLayer">
            // code
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to set `style="display: none"` the table that I've pointed, the first one with `class="esriLegendLaye`. Right now, I can do this:

```
document.getElementById("mapLegendInside").style["display"] = "none";
```

And I will hide the whole main `div` but, how can I pick only the table that I've pointed? Please, I can't add class or id to the tables or divs inside, this code is generated byt an external javascript library, I just need to pick that 2nd table inside the 2nd element (div) inside the div of the main div (haha).

here's a fiddle with that code to play with:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/coe0wa67/

Comment: why are you considering `esriLegendLayer` class? If it is for special use to select table then I think you checked with wrong answer. You can go through the answers and `check` for the best `answer`. It's for upcoming visitors as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`.

```js
// you can use `document.querySelector`
document.querySelector('#mapLegendInside table.esriLegendLayer').style.display = 'none';
// or - use `querySelectorAll`
setTimeout(() =>
document.querySelectorAll('#mapLegendInside table.esriLegendLayer')[0].style.display = 'block', 1000);
```

```html
<div id="mapLegendInside">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
      <table class="esriLegendLayerLabel">
        <tr>
          <td>Code - table.esriLegendLayerLabel</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="esriLegendLayer">
        <tr>
          <td>Code of the table that I need to hide</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="esriLegendLayer">
        <tr>
          <td>Code - table.esriLegendLayer</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pmirnd, this answer is the best which considers entire question details. If not then I think you need to update your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

An example for you would be

`var layers = document.querySelectorAll('.esriLegendLayer');`

Layers will be an array of the elements which have the class `esriLegendLayer`, you can change the selector you pass to be more or less specific as you need.

To only change the first you can use

`document.querySelector('.esriLegendLayer').style.display = 'none'`

Comment: document.querySelector('.esriLegendLayer').style.display = 'none'

Comment: @pmirnd You cannot put text directly in a table. It is working, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/tLupg4zc/

Comment: Not sure what you mean, on that page run `document.querySelector('.esriLegendLayer')`
and you will see `<table class=​"esriLegendLayer" style=​"display:​ none;​">​<!--- I need to hide this table ----></table>​`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the `table` structure. Add `tr` and `td` to the table and the following code will work

table example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>code</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`document.querySelectorAll("#mapLegendInside table")[2].style.display = "none";`

Comment: I think you should take care of `esriLegendLayer` class. Your answer has less information than the answer from @Alona Vereshaka. Check her answer.